# Configure view.yml per environment

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.2

I would like to configure view.yml per environment.

In production:

```
default:
  http_metas:
    content-type: text/json
```

In dev:

```
default:
  http_metas:
    content-type: text/html
```

I need this because I want to debug json response with web debug toolbar. So, I basically need to set content type of response per environment. Is it possible to do it yml? If not, what's the right place to hook into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it in view.yml without rewriting the entire view config handler. I suppose there are a couple of alternatives for this specific example:

- You could use the ysfDimensionsPlugin which allows you to specify different dimensions with different config files.
- You could achieve this by adding or extending a filter in the filter chain, I suppose I would do this by extending sfRenderingFilter.

If however, you just want to inspect JSON output, why not use Firebug or Web Inspector?

Comment: No, I would like to inspect database calls, etc.. in the web debug toolbar, which is only injected into the response if it is html content-type.

Answer (score 0):

Open file `lib/symfony/config/sfViewConfigHandler.class.php`

now replace **"mergeConfig"** function with below and your problem  will be solved :)

```
  protected function mergeConfig($myConfig)
  {
    // merge javascripts and stylesheets
    $myConfig['all']['stylesheets'] = array_merge(isset($myConfig['default']['stylesheets']) && is_array($myConfig['default']['stylesheets']) ? $myConfig['default']['stylesheets'] : array(), isset($myConfig['all']['stylesheets']) && is_array($myConfig['all']['stylesheets']) ? $myConfig['all']['stylesheets'] : array());
    unset($myConfig['default']['stylesheets']);

    $myConfig['all']['javascripts'] = array_merge(isset($myConfig['default']['javascripts']) && is_array($myConfig['default']['javascripts']) ? $myConfig['default']['javascripts'] : array(), isset($myConfig['all']['javascripts']) && is_array($myConfig['all']['javascripts']) ? $myConfig['all']['javascripts'] : array());
    unset($myConfig['default']['javascripts']);

    // merge default and all
    $myConfig['all'] = sfToolkit::arrayDeepMerge(
      isset($myConfig['default']) && is_array($myConfig['default']) ? $myConfig['default'] : array(),
      isset($myConfig['all']) && is_array($myConfig['all']) ? $myConfig['all'] : array(),
      isset($myConfig[sfConfig::get('sf_environment')]) && is_array($myConfig[sfConfig::get('sf_environment')]) ? $myConfig[sfConfig::get('sf_environment')] : array()
    );
    unset($myConfig['default']);
    $this->yamlConfig = $myConfig;
  }
```